# Do reference class generators have to have the same name as the class itself?

Tags: r, oop, reference-class

When I gave class generators different names to the class itself (there are legitimate reasons for doing this), I started running into problems:

```
myClassGen <- setRefClass("myClass",
    methods = list(foo = function() baz())
)
myClassGen$methods(baz = function() "baz")

myObj <- myClassGen()
myObj$foo()
```

resulted in:

```
Error in myObj$foo() : could not find function "baz"
```

yet method `baz` clearly exists because I can do:

```
> myObj$baz
Class method definition for method baz()
function () 
"baz"
<environment: 0x000000002c60f0b8>
```

The above error does not occur if the generator name is changed to `myClass`.

If this behavior is by design, why? If this is a bug, then how can I fix this issue? Are there another hidden problems resulting from generators and classes having different names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that `baz()` has to be called on the class instance, so on `.self` :

```
myClassGen <- setRefClass("myClass",methods = list(foo = function() .self$baz()))
myClassGen$methods(baz = function() "baz")

myObj <- myClassGen()
myObj$foo()
# [1] "baz"
```

So, the problem is not related to the name of the class generator being different from the class name, because the following code doesn't work (note the missing `.self`):

```
myClass <- setRefClass("myClass", methods = list(foo = function() baz()))
myClass$methods(baz = function() "baz")

myObj <- myClass()
myObj$foo()
# Error in myObj$foo() : could not find function "baz"
```

Official documentation on Reference Classes is [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/methods/html/refClass.html).

---

**EDIT (as per comment):**

The documentation in the section regarding `$methods(...)` function states:

> The new methods can refer to any currently defined method by name
>   (including other methods supplied in this call to $methods(). **Note
>   though that previously defined methods are not re-analyzed meaning
>   that they will not call the new method (unless it redefines an
>   existing method of the same name).**

If I understand correctly, this means that the new added method `baz` cannot be called by the previously defined method `foo`. If so, why does `.self$foo()` work fine ?
I'm not sure but I guess it has to do with the *analysis* of the methods mentioned in the text above.
Probably the methods defined through `setRefClass` are parsed and, if a call to another class method is found, the call is somehow explicitly linked to that class method to avoid confusion with a possibly existing function having the same name (as an oversimplification I imagine that these calls are prefixed by with `.self$`).
Instead, method calls to `.self$something()` are not modified since they are already explicit.

This seems reasonably supported by the following tests. For example if we run this code:

```
myClassGen <- setRefClass("myClass", methods = list(foo = function() baz(), 
                                                    baz = function() "baz"))
myObj <- myClassGen()
myObj$foo
```

we get:

```
Class method definition for method foo()
function () 
baz()
<environment: 0x000000000e490938>

 Methods used:  
    "baz"
```

where you can notice the last line stating that the class method `baz` is used by the `foo` method.

If we run this instead:

```
myClassGen <- setRefClass("myClass",methods = list(foo = function() .self$baz(), 
                                                   baz = function() "baz"))
myObj <- myClassGen()
myObj$foo
```

we get:

```
Class method definition for method foo()
function () 
.self$baz()
<environment: 0x00000000107ab5c8>
```

where there's no mention of the class method `baz`.

Comment: Ahh OK, thanks. So why do I not need to use `.self$baz()` if I create `foo` and `baz` in one go? Like `myClass <- setRefClass("myClass", methods = list(foo = function() baz(), baz = function() "baz"))`. Seems a little inconsistent in determining when `.self` is required.

Comment: Actually I don't know, probably it has something to do with the enclosing environments... anyway, I suggest to always use .self when you refer to a method of the current instance, to avoid confusion with a possibly existing function having the same name...

Comment: @MiloChen: edited the question wih some considerations about your comment ;)